# How to send an HTML array trought AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have these checkboxes :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="1" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="3" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="4" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="5" />
```

and this jquery handler :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.linkStyle').click(function(e) {
            // 
        });                 
    });
</script>
```

so, when I click on a checkbox, I'd like to send the array style[] to the server trought AJAX (with the actual values).

How can I do it?

**EDIT**

Tried :

```
$.post("list/browse_ajax.php", {id:"browseUpdate", actualArtist:browseArtist, actualEvent:browseEvent, actualData:browseData, style:$('#browseTableStyle:checkbox').serialize()},
    function(data) {
        $("#browseList").html(data);
    }
);
```

but the style[] is not send...

**EDIT 2** - Problem with serialize

This is the whole code :

```
<form id="browseForm">
    <div class="wideinfo">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="tableList1">
                Style
            </div>  

            <div class="tableList2">
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="Style1" checked="checked" /> Style1</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="Style2" /> Style2</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="Style3" checked="checked" /> Style3</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="Style4" checked="checked" /> Style4</span>
                <span><input type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="Style2" /> Style5</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

but with :

```
style:$('#browseForm').serialize()
```

it sends this (checked on Fiddler)

```
style: style%5B%5D=Style1&style%5B%5D=Style3&style%5B%5D=Style4
```

not :

```
style[]: Style1
style[]: Style3
style[]: Style4
```

The last is a real/comprensive HTML array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you finnaly have your string submitted `style%5B%5D=Style1&style%5B%5D=Style3&style%5B%5D=Style4` you can retrieve the comprehensive array like that:

```
parse_str($_POST['style'], $data);
```

The the `$data` variable contains:

```
array(
    "style" => array(
        0 => "Style1",
        1 => "Style3",
        2 => "Style4",
    )
)
```

Does it solve your problem ?

Comment: Yeah man, maybe...but why I should do it if I could send the data in the correct form? :) this is what I mean, analysed with Fiddler : http://img854.imageshack.us/f/examplek.jpg/ (send with standard submit/send with that function)

Comment: Hoo, I see better now. This is why you should put everything in the form and serilize everything alltogether. So that you won't have this issue. Another way would be to have a quite heavy js that manually extract all your data.

Comment: I found how to resolve it anyway :) Just I create a string as styles='style[]=Acid&style[]=Ambient&style[]=Big+Beat'; and I send it :)

Answer (score 4):

What about :

```
$.post('my-url', $(':checkbox').serialize(), function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    // my callback body
});
```

**EDIT:** Actually the serialize function only works on form (and thus serialize form fields). So you have to wrap your fields in a form. See bellow.

Comment: uhm... In fact I don't know that function aswell. $.ajax is not better?

Comment: $.load, $.post, $.get ... are just shortcuts to pre-configured $.ajax function.

Comment: $.post is a more specific version of $.ajax

Answer (score 1):

First, your callback does not seem to be consistent :

```
function(data) {
    $("#browseList").html(msg);
}
```

You might want to say :

```
function(data) {
    $("#browseList").html(data);
}
```

Also have you check firebug or your explorer javascript debuger to see if there is any error. Also can you show us the actual submited data. Finnaly what is the result of a call to :

```
$(':checkbox').serialize()
```

Comment: Yeah, the data-msg was a wrong copy and paste here :) No error on JS debugger. Tried to check the values with Fiddler : style is sent, but the value is empty...so it doesnt get the correct checkbox. P.S. they are into a div with id browseTableStyle , so I also try to use '#browseTableStyle:checkbox' , but nothing. Looks like the it arrive to the server as variable, not as array?!?!?! How can I see the result of $(':checkbox').serialize() ?

Comment: Yo can see the result of $(':checkbox').serialize() by typing it on your web development console. Also I checked and serialize is meant to be used on form element. So if you wrap your inputs in a form, you would do : $('form').serialize(). Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Reading the serialize doc, it create a string of values; I need an array of values; so I need to pass somethings like style[], not style and the values serialized...

Comment: I see your concern, but at the end the http post data are just a long string. PHP should unserialize the string for you and you will get a standard array. At least, it worked for me.

Comment: The result, passing the form with a normal request, is for example : style[]=1, style[]=3, style[]=4; on server side, this is an array, and I get it with $_GET['style'] on PHP; Do you understand what I mean? :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should work.

```
style:$('#browseForm').serialize()
```

At the end I strongly advise you to inclue all your post data in the form so that you can simply do:

```
$.post('my-url', $('form').serialize(), function(data){
    $("#browseList").html(data);
});
```

It is cleaner, straightforward and easier to maintain. After that your PHP script should handle the rest.

Comment: No man, is what I said : I get the string style%5B%5D=Style1&style%5B%5D=Style3&style%5B%5D=Style4...this is not an HTML array, is a string! If I send the form normally I'll send 3 variable called style[] (each) with the values : that's an array :)

Comment: Yea, but style%5B%5D is like style[]. So the serialized string is ok. So what you need to do is to inserialize it in your php, using parse_str for example : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-str.php.

Comment: Uhm..but how can I send different parameter (such as many style[]) with jQuery? That's I need to know :)